# Tricky upsert in Delta table using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a case class as follows:

```
case class UniqueException(
                                   ExceptionId:String,
                                   LastUpdateTime:Timestamp,
                                   IsDisplayed:Boolean,
                                   Message:String,
                                   ExceptionType:String,
                                   ExceptionMessage:String,
                                   FullException:String
                                 )
```

This is used to generate a Delta table.

Following conditions need to be met:

1. A new UniqueException needs to be inserted if the ExceptionId of the UniqueException is new to the delta table.
2. An existing UniqueException needs be updated if the ExceptionId of the incoming UniqueException exists already in the delta table and LastUpdateTime of the incoming UniqueException is greater than by 14 days.
3. If the LastUpdateTime is less than 14 days, then the incoming UniqueException should not be updated if the ExceptionId of the incoming UniqueException exists already in the delta table.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't satisfy the above cases.

```
val dfUniqueException = DeltaTable.forPath(outputFolder)
dfUniqueException.as("existing")
  .merge(dfNewExceptions.as("new"), "new.ExceptionId = existing.ExceptionId and new.LastUpdateTime >  date_add(existing.LastUpdateTime, 14")
  .whenMatched().updateAll()
  .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
  .execute()
```

Any idea how the above conditions can be fulfilled with a single merge statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your rules can be rewritten as follow:

- **if** there is an existing exception

  - **if** `LastUpdateTime` difference between existing and new is more than 14 days, update existing
  - **else** do nothing
- **else** insert new exception

So you can change your code to put the "14 days rule" in `whenMatched` clause and not in `merge` clause, as follow:

```scala
import io.delta.tables.DeltaTable

val dfUniqueException = DeltaTable.forPath(outputFolder)
val dfNewExceptionLabeled = dfNewExceptions.as("new")

dfUniqueException.as("existing")
  .merge(dfNewExceptionLabeled, "new.ExceptionId = existing.ExceptionId")
  .whenMatched("new.LastUpdateTime > date_add(existing.LastUpdateTime, 14)")
  .updateAll()
  .whenNotMatched()
  .insertAll()
  .execute()
```

If you apply this code with following existing exceptions:

```
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|ExceptionId    |LastUpdateTime     |Message |
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|exception_id_01|2021-03-10 00:00:00|value_01|
|exception_id_02|2021-03-10 00:00:00|value_02|
|exception_id_03|2021-03-10 00:00:00|value_03|
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

And the following new exceptions:

```
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|ExceptionId    |LastUpdateTime     |Message |
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|exception_id_02|2021-03-20 00:00:00|value_04|
|exception_id_03|2021-03-31 00:00:00|value_05|
|exception_id_04|2021-03-31 00:00:00|value_06|
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

You final result in delta table is:

```
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|ExceptionId    |LastUpdateTime     |Message |
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
|exception_id_04|2021-03-31 00:00:00|value_06|
|exception_id_01|2021-03-10 00:00:00|value_01|
|exception_id_03|2021-03-31 00:00:00|value_05|
|exception_id_02|2021-03-10 00:00:00|value_02|
+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: @vincent I get an error pn PySpark saying `AttributeError: 'DeltaMergeBuilder' object has no attribute 'whenMatched'`

Comment: What is your version of DeltaLake ?